# Which exceptions invalidates a java socket?

Tags: java

Which sub-types of IOException relating to socket IO makes a java socket invalid for resue when thrown. SocketException, InterruptedIOException, ...?

Answer (score 1):

All of them except `SocketTimeoutException` on a read, and exceptions arising out of getting or setting socket options.

Comment: Yeah. SocketTimeoutException make sense. Was not sure about the others. Thanks EJP